# How to initialize value from Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to initialize a TextEditingController with a value from Firestore and like some help understanding how to do this within the initState function. On initState, I want to call the document and set the TextEditingController to the value of the document field titled "author". Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    var document = Firestore.instance.collection('books').document('Harry Potter').get();
    _authorController = new TextEditingController(text: document['author']);

}
```

How do I structure this call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a new async method than call it in `initState()`

```
void initialize() async{
 var document = await Firestore.instance.collection('books').document('Harry Potter').get();
    _authorController = new TextEditingController(text: document['author']);
}


@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
   initialize();

}
```

*I would recommend to send the `document['author']` as parameter from the parent widget to this widget instead of call it here.*

Answer (score 1):

to be able to consult information from firebase you need to make an asynchronous call, already using the keyword `async` or`then`.

example with `async`:

```
class SomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SomePageState createState() => _SomePageState();
}

class _SomePageState extends State<SomePage> {
    final _authorController = new TextEditingController();
    final _firestore = Firestore.instance;

    // Async Method
    void initAuthor() async {
        // we use the try catch to get an error in case an error happens with firestore
        try {
             final documentSnapshot = await _firestore.collection('books').document('Harry Potter').get();
            _authorController.text = documentSnapshot.data['author'];
        }catch(e){
            print(e);
        }
    }

   @override
   void initState() {
     super.initState();
     initAuthor();
   }
}
```

example with `then`:

```
class SomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SomePageState createState() => _SomePageState();
}

class _SomePageState extends State<SomePage> {
    final _authorController = new TextEditingController();
    final _firestore = Firestore.instance;

    void initAuthor() {
        final documentSnapshot = _firestore.collection('books')
             .document('Harry Potter')
             .get()
             .then((documentSnapshot) {
                 _authorController.text = documentSnapshot.data['author'];
             }).catchError((error){
                 print(error);
             });

    }

   @override
   void initState() {
     super.initState();
     initAuthor();
   }
}
```